# \dimexpr \numexpr & calc package

Tags: calculations, lengths

Why doesn't this work? I use Windows, TeX Live 2012 and pdfLaTeX

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}

\newlength{\perclenght}

\setlength{\perclenght}{%
                      \dimexpr%
                      ((((336pt*675pt)*(100-7.5))/100)/\textwidth)-\textheight%
                      \relax%
                      }%

\begin{document}
\the\perclenght
\end{document}
```

Comment: Even though the result is a length unit, I believe that `calc` does not allow multiplication of lengths. In other words: it does not work because it is not featured.

Comment: @tohecz thanks how can i solve? i want to put this code into a .sty file package

Comment: @FormlessCloud You have to write a proper dimension expression, which this is not. For example, `336pt*675pt` would be an area, not a length.

Comment: As well, I'm not sure if you really wish to call the length `\perclengHT` with the typo (it should be `lengTH`).

Comment: but latex must need to know that 336pt*675pt is an area? to calculate the result of this expression?

Comment: @JosephWright literaly speaking, it is a proper dimension expression, because after you finish the calculations, you get a 1-D dimension.

Comment: What @tohecz said. In addition the same is true of the e-tex `\dimexpr` The intermediate result `336pt*675pt` would require being able to store an area which neither can do. (Incidentally using both calc and \dimexpr at the same time might be thought adventurous: I think it probably works out that it is parsed as a \dimexpr and so calc isn't really used, but that's probably by luck more than anything as the original calc package at least predated the e-tex primitives.

Comment: @tohecz It's not a dimension expression _as defined by the e-TeX manual_, which is what is important here. There are many things which would give a dimension 'at the end' which will fail to parse correctly. For example `\dimexpr 10*5 pt\relax` is invalid but `\dimexpr 5pt*10\relax` is valid, as the dimension has to 'come first'.

Comment: @JosephWright I know. I just meant that the "maths behind it" is correct, but the current implementation does not allow it.

Comment: I did the following `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{pgf}\newlength\perclength\pgfmathsetlength{\perclength}{{(((3.36*675)*(1-0.075))/\the\textwidth) -\the\textheight}}\begin{document}\the\perclength\end{document}` and found  -543.91911 pt. A weird number to use. Also you are likely to get `Dimension too large` error for the multiplication.

Answer (score 3):

**THANKS TO PERCUSSE**

this is the answer, is right?

```
    \RequirePackage{pgf}%
\newlength\perclength\pgfmathsetlength{\perclength}{%
                                                   ((((3.36*6.75)*(1-(7.5/100)))/(\textwidth/100))-(\textheight/100))*100%
                                                   }%
```