# Explicit artihmetic functions as alternative to calc

Tags: calculations, lengths

Is there a way to perform compile time arithmetic with explicit functions that respect dimensions? Here is a strawman example of arithmetic functions:

```
\mul{4}{7}            % expands to 28
\mul{4}{6pt}          % expands to 24pt
\mul{0.3}{\linewidth} % expand into some kind of anonymous length-like value
                      %   storing 0.3 * the current value of \linewidth.
\add{0.3pt}{0.2pt}    % expands to 0.5pt
```

For instance, the following document uses scalar multiplication with widths:

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex

% \usepackage{lipsum}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TimesNewRoman}
\setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Arial}

\begin{document}

\hspace*{0.5 \linewidth}

\begin{minipage}{0.4 \linewidth}
The quick brown fox jumped
over the lazy dog
\end{minipage}


\end{document}
```

The notation `0.4 \linewidth` is convenient and easy to read, but isn't composable. For instance, using `\begin{minipage}{0.4 {0.8 \linewidth}}` instead produces the error:

```
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
{
l.15 \begin{minipage}{0.4 {0.8 \linewidth}}
```

Using `\usepackage{calc}` doesn't make the `0.4 {0.8 \linewidth}` construction valid, either.

Is there a way to perform arithmetic explicitly?

NB: this questions differs from [this one here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112150/what-is-the-most-convenient-way-to-do-general-arithmetic-calculations-involving) because it's asking for the most *explicit* way to perform arithmetic, rather than the most *convenient*.

Comment: `\dimexpr` isn't explicit enough? Or features from `expl3`?

Comment: I just noticed your `% !TEX TS-program = lualatex` if you are using luatex then of course you have the full Lua math expression language available at all times. So you have arithmetic, trig, square roots etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `xfp` to do floating point arithmetic.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp}

\begin{document}

\noindent
X\hspace*{0.5 \linewidth}X

\noindent
X\hspace*{\fpeval{0.3*0.5}\linewidth}X

\noindent
X\hspace*{\fpeval{(sin(3))^2+(cos(3))^2}\linewidth}X

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{\fpeval{0.4*0.8}\linewidth}
The quick brown fox jumped
over the lazy dog
\end{minipage}

\noindent\rule{0.32\linewidth}{0.4pt}

\noindent\rule{\fpeval{0.4*0.8}\linewidth}{0.4pt}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can use pretty complex expressions (that one above is of course 1).

You can even mix `calc` syntax with this, where it is accepted: with `\usepackage{calc}` something like

```
\setlength{\foo}{\fpeval{sqrt(2)}\linewidth-45pt}
```

would be valid if `\foo` is a length parameter.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "compile time" in TeX as it isn't a compiler, there is no compile stage separate from execution however assuming you are using etex you have inline arithmetic expressions available

```
  \begin{minipage}{0.4 \dimexpr 0.8 \linewidth\relax}
```

or

```
   \setcounter{section}{\numexpr 4 * 7\relax}
```

Comment: I meant to use _compile time_ somewhat metaphorically to distinguish the arithmetic I want from arithmetic operations appearing in typeset math. _Compile time_ seemed like a decent analogy because all traces of the arithmetic are removed in the output document. What's the appropriate way to refer to it?

Comment: "assuming you are using etex", doesn't LaTeX require it for some time?

Comment: @jfbu yes (it's good to assume things that are true)