# How to calculate in Latex?

Tags: includegraphics

I have following problem:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centerline{\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{relations.png}}
\caption{Example of a figure caption.}
\label{fig}
\end{figure}
```

the image is a little bit too big if I do this above.
Instead, I'd like the width to be about 10px smaller.

I tried the following:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centerline{\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth - 10px]{relations.png}}
\caption{Example of a figure caption.}
\label{fig}
\end{figure}
```

But it doesn't work.

How can I adjust the width of the image by a few pixels?

Comment: Try width=.95\linewidth.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @RaffaeleSantoro thank you for your help! But I have to ask: isn't it possible to use minus and plus?

Comment: `width=\dimexpr \columnwidth -10pt`.

Comment: @YasinSahin Unrelated to your question, but better use `\centering\includegraphics[...]{...}` instead of `\centerline`

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What is the most convenient way to do general-arithmetic calculations involving lengths?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/112150/5764)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reduce the width of the image by 10px, you can use the "\dimexpr" command to subtract 10px from the width of the image.

Example:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centerline{\includegraphics[width=\dimexpr\columnwidth-10px\relax]{relations.png}}
  \caption{Example of a figure caption.}
  \label{fig}
\end{figure}
```

You can also use the "\hspace*{-10px}" command to shift the image 10px to the left, which will effectively reduce the width of the image by 10px. Here is an example of how you can do this:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centerline{\hspace*{-10px}\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{relations.png}}
  \caption{Example of a figure caption.}
  \label{fig}
\end{figure}
```